# Php application started working slowly with docker

Tags: php, docker

I am sure it is too general question. But still hope to get some helpful advice.

So I use vagrant to run our php application, we use postgres, rabbitmq and memcached. I set up docker environment. Here's my docker-compose.yml

```
web:
  build: app
  ports: 
    - "80:80" 
  volumes:
    - /Users/ihorsamusenko/my/project:/var/www/app
  links:
    - db
    - rabbit
    - memcached
db:
  build: postgres
  ports:
    - 5432:5432
  environment:
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
    POSTGRES_USER: postgres
rabbit:
  image: rabbitmq
memcached:
  image: memcached
```

But with such setup application started working much slower than it used to do. 
I understand that probably my problem is application specific. But still, maybe there are some common tips for such problems.

Comment: What do you mean by "started working much slower"? It might be the time it takes for the docker containers to boot?

Comment: Average request time grew to 5 s while usually it is 2 sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you are using VirtualBox on Windows or Mac OS X.

What is likely causing this is the slow volume sharing performance of VirtualBox. Some references:

- https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=10052837
- https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/593
- https://superuser.com/questions/859149/slow-disk-performance-in-docker-container

Basically, you will need to experiment with some other sharing methods (NFS, xhyve, Vagrant rsync) to get up to more native performance.

Comment: yes, you're right Mac OS X. I removed volume from docker-compose.yml and it started working as it works in vagrant. So yes, problem is about the volumes.

Comment: as I understand there is no a silver bullet for using Docker for development , is there ?

Comment: No, not at the moment. The alternatives I've listed all come with their own quirks as well. You will end up trading the performance issue for a permission issue or more complicated setup. Dynamic languages don't really favor local Docker development right now.

Comment: This seems like a big disadvantage to me. Thanks for clarify, Andy.